# (Un)tidy a dataset with unequal sizes and duplicate variables

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2)), 
    y = c(1, 2, 6, 8, 3)
)
```

I need to (un)tidy it so that it looks like this:

```
df_new <- data.frame(
    A = c(1, 2, 6),
    B = c(8, 3, NA)
)
```

`tidyr::spread` threw duplicate value errors....

Comment: Most would consider your data tidy as-is, and what you're doing to it it to be "untidying,"

Comment: Ha. I guess you are right. I need to untidy it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tidyr` (to my knowledge) won't let you do this without an ID column. So we'll add that first and then spread:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(x) %>% 
    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
    spread(key = x, value = y, fill = NA)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      id     A     B
# * <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     8
# 2     2     2     3
# 3     3     6    NA
```

You can, of course, remove the `id` column at the end if you prefer.

Comment: Damn. I just figured it out, but you beat me. Your solution is a lot more elegant, anyways. Thanks!

Comment: 1:n() might be shorter, but row_number() is a lot more readable ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `base R` with `unstack` to create a `list`, then pad with `NA` at the end to make the length same for each `list` element and convert to `data.frame`

```
lst <- unstack(df, y~x)
data.frame(lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
#  A  B
#1 1  8
#2 2  3
#3 6 NA
```

---

Or if we are using a package, a compact option would be

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(split(df$y, df$x))
```

The output will be string which can be changed to `numeric`

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr, tidyr::complete, ::spread

```
df_new <- df %>%
    group_by(x) %>% 
    mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
    complete(index = 1:max(index)) %>% 
    spread(x, y, fill = NA) %>% 
    select(-index)
```